# How to convert multiple columns into single column in snowflake table using query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table "**TABLE1**" like below

```
Date        src_counrty  src_State   dst_country    dst_state   Value
2022-02-09       a           d           x             y          1
2022-02-09       a           e           x             y          1
2022-02-09       c           f           x             y          1
```

I want to have output table as below using a select statement

```
Date         src    dst   Value
2022-02-09    a      x      1
2022-02-09    a      x      1
2022-02-09    c      x      1
2022-02-09    d      y      1
2022-02-09    e      y      1
2022-02-09    f      y      1
2022-02-09    a      y      1
2022-02-09    a      y      1
2022-02-09    c      y      1
2022-02-09    d      x      1
2022-02-09    e      x      1
2022-02-09    f      x      1
```

As seen in output table column src_counrty  and src_State is merged as single column "**src**" and dst_country and dst_state as "**dst**"
Is there any way to achieve this output using SQL query!

I have searched related topics on the internet and could not find any, so if anyone has any suggestion/solution for this it will be much helpful for me.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a series of unions:

```sql
SELECT Date, src_counrty, dst_country, Value FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT Date, src_State, dst_country, Value FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT Date, src_counrty, dst_state, Value FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT Date, src_State, dst_state, Value FROM TABLE1
ORDER BY Date;
```

If the order of the output matters beyond the date, state the logic and the above query can be updated.